# Match date with day of week?

Tags: flutter, dart

getDaysInWeek() lists the days from Sun to Sat.

getSevenInWeek() lists the first week of 2019. Jan 01 should be on Tues not Sun.

How do you match the date with the day of the week using the weekday property under DateTime class or the Date_Utils package?

[image: match date with day of week]

```
class ThirdRouteState extends State<ThirdRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Calendar Page"),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Table(
          children: <TableRow>[
            TableRow(
              children: getDaysInWeek(),
            ),
            TableRow(
              children: getSevenInWeek(),
            ),
          ],
        ),

      ]),
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> getSevenInWeek() {
  var seven = <DateTime>[];
  DateTime start = DateTime(2019, 01, 01);
  final end = DateTime(2019, 01, 08);
  while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    seven.add(start);
    start = start.add(const Duration(days: 1));
  }

  return seven.map((DateTime time) {
    return Text(
      new DateFormat("dd").format(time),
      style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    );
  }).toList();
}

List<Widget> getDaysInWeek() {
  List<Widget> dayWidgets = [];

  Utils.weekdays.forEach(
    (day) {
      dayWidgets.add(
        new CalendarTile(
          isDayOfWeek: true,
          dayOfWeek: day,
        ),
      );
    },
  );

  return dayWidgets;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the days inside the `getSevenInWeek` function. Do it in the State class like so, then pass it to both `getSevenInWeek` and `getDaysInWeek`:

```dart
// no need for a library.
String getDay(int dayNumber) {
  List<String> weekdays = const [
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat",
    "Sun",
  ];
  return weekdays[dayNumber];
}

class ThirdRouteState extends State<ThirdRoute> {
  List<DateTime> seven = <DateTime>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    seven = <DateTime>[];
    DateTime start = DateTime(2019, 01, 01);
    DateTime end = DateTime(2019, 01, 08);
    while (start.isBefore(end)) {
      seven.add(start);
      start = start.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Calendar Page"),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Table(
          children: <TableRow>[
            TableRow(
              children: getDaysInWeek(seven),
            ),
            TableRow(
              children: getSevenInWeek(seven),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> getSevenInWeek(List<DateTime> days) {
  return days.map((DateTime time) {
    return Text(
      new DateFormat("dd").format(time),
      style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    );
  }).toList();
}

List<Widget> getDaysInWeek(List<DateTime> days) {
  List<Widget> dayWidgets = [];

  days.forEach(
    (DateTime day) {
      dayWidgets.add(
        new CalendarTile(
          isDayOfWeek: true,
          dayOfWeek: getDay(day.weekday),
        ),
      );
    },
  );

  return dayWidgets;
}
```